# Output window in Visual Studio 2013 does not show output from Debug or Trace

Tags: git, visual-studio, debugging

My output window in Visual Studio 2013 does not allow me to change "Show output from:" to "Debug".  The only options I have in that field are, Build, Build Order, Source Control-Git, and Tests.  How do I enable Debug and Trace so that they appear in the Output window?

Answer (score 2):

It should automatically change to 'Debug' after you 'Start Debugging' (F5), and remain there henceforth. Assuming that the project builds.

Is this a new project that you've never built? In that case I think it isn't there initially, but I don't have VS at hand to confirm this now.